# Restrict File Upload types on Django

Tags: python, django, security

I am implementing a way to restrict file upload on Django 1.8 running python 3.4

Basically, I want to check the MIMEType of a file when they upload using `mimetype`. However, when I manipulate the file name from `bad_image.exe` to `bad_image.exe.jpg`, the mimetype is still `image/jpeg`. This could still result in a malicious attack.

Is there a way to actually implement this? I tried `magic` too but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, rename a file `.exe` to `.exe.jpg` and `content_type` output `(image/jpeg)`.

But using [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/blob/master/README.md) if properly check the file as checking their headers and not the extension, so the output was in my test:

`PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows`

Even so I think the headers may be modified... hope that helps.

---

**EDIT:** In my test use [cleaning a specific attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileTestUpload
        fields = ('title','file')

    def clean_file(self):

       f = self.cleaned_data.get("file", False)
       ftype = magic.from_buffer(f.read()) # InMemoryUploadedFile 

       print ftype

       return f
```

It is too simple but it was just to test.

Comment: hello, can i ask then, how do i get access to the uploaded file since the file is stored in memory?

Comment: I updated the answer. in this case, upload the file, but you can check types and extensions and send form errors.